# Is Not Sharing knowledge a sin?

Tags: halal-haram, hadith-interpretation

I listen to Islamic lectures on youtube, most of them which have taught me a number of things Alhamdulillah.
But I came across a hadith which says, "There is no man who memorizes knowledge then conceals it, but he will be brought forth on the Day of Resurrection bridled with reins of fire." (Hasan) Another chain with similar wording. (Sunan ibn Majah)..

And similar narrations like that and a verse form the quran which stated that concealing knowledge is a sin.. .
Does this mean that It is obligatory for me to share with other people through texts or  conversations, whatever hadith or verse or beneficial lessons I have learnt?

Comment: This is mainly the same question as what I have asked before in https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/46777/when-is-hiding-knowledge-a-sin

Comment: Jazakllah khair.. I read them.. but still .. if it is like. .  I know that 12 rawatib prayers if performed, Allah will build a house for him in Jannah. Most of thle people around me dont really know that.  Is it a sin if I don't tell them about this?