# Is hiding knowledge haram if the people already know it?

Tags: sin, punishment, family

Is it haram if i get some knowledge and i don’t tell anyone because they already know that knowledge?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When is hiding knowledge a sin?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/46777/when-is-hiding-knowledge-a-sin)

Answer (score 0):

salaam,
I don't think it is haram since they already know the information. If they didn't, then it might be a different scenario. Hope that helps:)
MuslimGap.

Comment: What anybody thinks is not a basis for a good and helpful answer. We expect answers here to be well elaborated, in your own words and claims to be supported by evidences (see [answer]).

Comment: it is hard to be elaborate when the question  is vague. We don't know the scenario and we don't know what kind of info it is. Thus, the answer is general. We cannot label everything as haram when we do not know the whole story. This is why I wrote, "I think". :)

Comment: Then you'd better ask for clarification by comment, that's much better than saying whatever or guessing what is meant.

Comment: my apologies. I am new, but will ask for clarification in the future and thanks for the suggestion. :)